# How exactly do @angular and @type dependencies work?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

> This questions has probably been asked before but I couldn't find all the answers. If that's the case, sorry.

I'm pretty familiar with how `package.json` and `dependencies / dev-dependencies` work for Node apps.

Now I'm studying Angular 2 and the first thing that struck me was: **What are those dependencies starting with @angular and @type? How do they work?**

I realized they have 2 things I'm not used to:

1. They start with an @
2. They are linear in the name (`@angular/something`), but inside `node_modules` they are hierarchical.

So, is this an Angular/Typescript specific thing, or it's just something about NPM that I didn't know about?

I mean, if I publich an NPM package called `@banana/core`, is it going to work and inside my `node_modules` I'll have a folder called `@banana` with another one called `core` inside, or is it specific to Angular or TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not specific to Angular or TypeScript -- it is an NPM feature allowing for grouping of modules:

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope